# Trouble finding the 2 values in this Tradingview script

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to add the crossing of the two lines (red and blue) in the indicator as part of my enterlong and entershort trading conditions but cant seem to figure out the 2 lines. I'd like to have them at a < or > and have tried enterlong = (val > signalperiod) , (val > ma) but can't seem to figure it out

```
length = input(20, title="BB Length")
mult = input(2.0,title="BB MultFactor")
lengthKC=input(20, title="KC Length")
multKC = input(1.5, title="KC MultFactor")
SignalPeriod=input(5, title="Signal Length")

useTrueRange = input(true, title="Use TrueRange (KC)", type=bool)

// Calculate BB
source = close
basis = sma(source, length)
dev = multKC * stdev(source, length)
upperBB = basis + dev
lowerBB = basis - dev

// Calculate KC
ma = sma(source, lengthKC)
range = useTrueRange ? tr : (high - low)
rangema = sma(range, lengthKC)
upperKC = ma + rangema * multKC
lowerKC = ma - rangema * multKC

sqzOn  = (lowerBB > lowerKC) and (upperBB < upperKC)
sqzOff = (lowerBB < lowerKC) and (upperBB > upperKC)
noSqz  = (sqzOn == false) and (sqzOff == false)

val = linreg(source  -  avg(avg(highest(high, lengthKC), lowest(low, 
lengthKC)),sma(close,lengthKC)), 
        lengthKC,0)

bcolor = iff( val > 0, 
        iff( val > nz(val[1]), lime, green),
        iff( val < nz(val[1]), red, maroon))
scolor = noSqz ? blue : sqzOn ? black : gray 
plot(val, color=blue, linewidth=2)
plot(0, color=scolor, style=cross, linewidth=2)
plot(sma(val,SignalPeriod), color=red, linewidth=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The blue line is `val` and the red line is `sma(val,SignalPeriod)`.

Once we know this, we can use the `crossover()` and `crossunder()` functions to check if they crossed each other.

For example:

```
val_sma = sma(val,SignalPeriod)

enterlong = crossover(val, val_sma)
entershort = crossunder(val, val_sma)
```